# Someone who is about to make a decision

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for someone who is, sooner or later, about to make a (potentially critical) decision? (I am trying to construct a headline as "Letter to X" where X is the word I am looking for.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "decision-maker". It is frequently used in business and government contexts. "The business analyst prepares figures to aid the decision-maker." " I want to put my case directly to the decision-maker."